# maximum gap between two 1s in a binary equivalent of a decimal number

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to write a program to find the maximum gap between two 1s in a binary equivalent of a decimal number. For example for 100101: the gap is 2 and for 10101: the gap is 1.

```
<?php
$numberGiven = 251;
$binaryForm = decbin($numberGiven);

$status = false;
$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($binaryForm); $i++)
{
    var_dump($binaryForm[$i]);
    if($binaryForm[$i] == 1)
    {
        $status = false;
        $count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $status = true;
        $count += 1;
    }
}
echo "count = " . $count . "<br>";
echo $binaryForm;
?>
```

but i was not successfull..

Comment: How was it not successful? Do you get errors; if so, which? Do you get any output at all; if so, which?

Comment: Is this homework, or is there a specific use-case for this? Maybe someone could suggest a different approach altogether.

Comment: Yes...you need to provide more information in order for us to adequately answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [binary right-shift operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) `>>` and iteratively shift by 1 bit and check if the current rightmost bit is a `1` until I've checked all the bits. If a `1` was found, the gap between the previous `1` is calculated:

```
foreach(array(5,17,25,1223243) as $number) {
    $lastpos = -1; 
    $gap = -1; // means there are zero or excatly one '1's

    // PHP_INT_SIZE contains the number of bytes an integer
    // will consume on your system. The value * 8 is the number of bits.
    for($pos=0; $pos < PHP_INT_SIZE * 8; $pos++) {
        if(($number >> $pos) & 1) {
            if($lastpos !== -1) {
                $gap = max($gap, $pos - $lastpos -1);
            }
            $lastpos = $pos;
        }
    }   

    echo "$number " . decbin($number) . "  ";
    echo "max gap: {$gap}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
5 101  max gap: 1
17 10001  max gap: 3
25 11001  max gap: 2
1223243 100101010101001001011  max gap: 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would request you to please help me understand the solution better. I am really not able to understand what was your approach.

Comment: It is binary logic I'm using. Why I `&` a number if `1` I can check if the right most byte is a `1`. If you then right shift every bit one after another you can count the `1`s. and the gap between them.

Comment: `function solution($N) { return max(array_map('strlen', explode('1', decbin($N)))); }`

Comment: Hey @HADI I encourage you to post that as an answer. I'm also curious about some performance testing here, probably your's is even faster.

Comment: @hek2mgl don't know about performance testing. Just tested code and works like charms. But I have strong believe that this code will have low performance. FYI, topic is closed so added comment here.

Answer (score 5):

First use regex to find "0" groups, then sort by length, descending—take the first one in the list, and get it's length:

```
$numberGiven = 37;
$binaryForm = decbin($numberGiven);

// get all groups of "0", put list in $matches
preg_match_all('/(0+)/', $binaryForm, $matches_all);
$matches = $matches_all[0];

// sort descending
rsort($matches, SORT_STRING);

// get first `$matches[0]` and print string length
echo 'count = ' . strlen($matches[0]) . '<br>';
echo $binaryForm;
```

UPDATED: based on Mark Baker's comments below.

UPDATE #2: As brought up by afeijo in the comments below, the above does not exclude ending zeros. Here's a solution for that:

```
preg_match_all('/(0+)1/', $binaryForm, $matches_all);
$matches = $matches_all[1];
```

Comment: No need for a usort: `preg_match_all('/1(0+)/', $data, $matches);
sort($matches[1], SORT_STRING);
$length = strlen(array_pop($matches[1]));
var_dump($length);`

Comment: nice code but this solution does not count for ending zeros. It should match only bettween 1's

Answer (score 3):

What you currently are doing is reseting the count each time you find a `1`.

You need to keep track of the current max value:

```
$count = 0;
$maxCount = 0;
```

and where you set `$count = 0` you should also do

```
if ($count > $maxCount)
  $maxCount = $count;
$count = 0;
```

then

```
echo "count = " . $maxCount . "<br>";
```

In all:

```
<?php
$numberGiven = 251;
$binaryForm = decbin($numberGiven);

$status = false;    
$count = 0;
$maxCount = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($binaryForm); $i++)
{
  // Don't count leading zeroes.
  if ($status == false && $binaryForm[$i] == 0) continue;
  $status = true;

  var_dump($binaryForm[$i]);

  // We've found a 1. Remember the count.
  if($binaryForm[$i] == 1)
  {
    if ($count > $maxCount)
      $maxCount = $count;
    $count = 0;
  }
  // We found a 0. Add one to count.
  else
  {
    $count += 1;
  }
}

echo "count = " . $count . "<br>";
echo $binaryForm;
?>
```

**Disclaimer:** *Code not tested*

Comment: `function solution($N) {$binaryForm = decbin($N);
    preg_match_all('/(0*)1/', $binaryForm, $matches);
    rsort( $matches[1], SORT_STRING);
    if($matches[1][0] !=''){
    return strlen($matches[1][0]);    
    }
    return 0;   
}`